# ORM convert-mapping is creating the wrong file structure

Tags: symfony, orm, silex, directory-structure

I currently got orm set up on my silex application. Everything seems to work as expected except for when I run the command to generate the entities from my database (reverse-engineering).

```
../../../vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Random\MyApp\Model\Random\Entities" --force --from-database annotation ./../random/entities
```

This command will create all of my entities perfectly but they will be under the folder structure

```
./../random/entities/Random/MyApp/Model/Random/Entities/(files here)
```

which is wrong since I am expecting to have

```
./../random/entities/(files here)
```

Answer (score 0):

A namespace is actually the path under your entities are grouped. So it's perfectly logic that doctrine generates files under this namespace.

If you want a file structure like it just do :

```
../../../vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping --namespace="random/entities" --force --from-database annotation ./
```

But this is definitely not conform with the PSR-0